# require(/var/www/bajwa-crm/vendor/composer/../symfony/polyfill-ctype/bootstrap.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, codeigniter, nginx, composer-php

[image]

My project is working fine on local but when I am uploading it on server then it is showing this error dont know what is this.

Comment: it is path issue. or try run composer update on the server again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem when I have had migrated a drupal website to new server...
To solve the problem I just used the composer command:

1. First cd into website directory, EX:
   `cd /var/www/your_website`
2. Run composer to install drupal 8 dependencies that it's need in the website directory;

`composer install`

If you use the sudo command, make sure the `.../vendor` directory has the right permission to be accessed by the user who in the `/var/www`directory;

`sudo composer install`